# Display contents selected from database in a text box or any view

Tags: java, android, database

I have 4 info, tat i get frm database. I want to view all of them in a view XML.

```
viewCr=viewDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CONTACTS",null);
    while(viewCr.getCount()!=0)
    {

    }
```

PLease help me filling the while loop :|

Comment: There are tons of examples out there on google

Comment: knowledge is evrywhere dude. Jst trying to collect info from experties :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting data from viewCr cursor try this:

```
viewCr=viewDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CONTACTS",null);
if (viewCr != null) {
viewCr.moveToFirst(); 

     while(!viewCr.isAfterLast())
    {
      myTextView.append(viewCr.getString(viewCr.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")));
      //Your code...
      viewCr.moveNext();
    } 
    //close cursor here
   viewCr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or can try this as well

```
viewCr.moveToFirst();
    do {
        // 
    } while (viewCr.moveToNext());
```

or ...

```
viewCr.moveToFirst();
    while(!viewCr .isAfterLast()) {

        viewCr.moveToNext();
    }
```

Comment: no that's fine ... but I never used that way in past ..will try soon definitely....... :)

Comment: cursor is viewCr plz change it